# escape special chartcter in detail view c#

Tags: c#

i have field in databaase. which contains special characters. i want to escape these chartacters while showing this field in detail view. eg: `B.Tech (E&amp;TC )` is the field value in table. i want show like `B.Tech(E&TC)`.

FYI: This is done while inserting value in database for some pupose.

Comment: Where are you displaying these? If a website, then this is the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)